# modify javascript block in header from codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I have a javascript block in aspx page.

What I want is to modify it from codebehind.

For example

I have code behind where array with countries is populated. I want to access this array in my aspx javascript block in header section.

Methods like "RegisterClientScriptBlock" can not used because they inject javascript in different block inside form tag

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: there are many countries and each country has many cities, what r u suggesting?

Comment: my bad I did not read good your question.

Comment: any solution for the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field to store your country data that both your javascript and code-behind can access. Not sure there is an easier way...

Comment: there are many countries and each country has several cities. are u still suggesting this?

Comment: Sure. Stick a json object with the complex structure you need as the value of your hidden field and then use javascript to parse it and use it whichever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
HtmlGenericControl newControl = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
newControl.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
newControl.InnerText = "something here...";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(newControl);
```

Comment: It will create new javascript block and code in that block can not be access in other javascript block